# Java recursive method to find factorial returns negative output

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I know it is overflow but the thing is 20 is relatively small number this should not happen right? is there a better approach to find factorial of large numbers such as 1000 with out getting this bizarre result?

```
public class RecursiveFunctionsExamples {

public int factorial(Integer n)
{
    Integer res;
    if(n == 0){ 
        res = 1;
    }else{
       res =  n * factorial(n-1);
    }

    return res;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new RecursiveFunctionsExamples().factorial(20));
}
}
```

Comment: factorial of 20 is too large to hold in `int`.

Comment: Research "integer overflow".

Comment: use `long` instead...

Comment: @NicholasK And face same problem later for bigger values :)

Comment: @Pshemo : after that use `BigInteger` ;)

Comment: @Pshemo I know this might be idiot question but I have to ask, does integer overflow or other types have relationship with RAM size? or is it strictly software related?

Comment: @NicholasK when I use BigInteger I get bad operand type for this line n == 0, n is of type BigInteger

Comment: @AbdalnassirGhzawi : You can't assign an `int` to a `BigInteger`. Just added an answer based on *your comments question*. Happy coding.

Comment: @AbdalnassirGhzawi No, it is related to fact that primitive types have fixed size (like `int` is stored on 32 bits, regardless of what value it holds so if value is too big and requires more bits, extra ones are discarded). Fixed size allows application to reserve proper amount of RAM and manage it (to know where "block" storing values starts and ends). 32 bits for `int` ware chosen most likely because that was most common architecture used when Java was created (32 bit processor).

Comment: A simple way to estimate the size of N! is Math.LogGamma( N+1), This shows, for example that 20! needs around 62 bits, and 1000! around 8530 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is marked duplicate, but solving it using `recursion` and `BigInteger` just coz you  (@Abdalnassir Ghzawi) requested for it.

```
public BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger res;
    if (n == BigInteger.ZERO) {
        res = BigInteger.ONE;
    } else {
        res = n.multiply(factorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    }

    return res;
}
```

You'll need to call it using :

```
System.out.println(new RecursiveFunctionsExamples().factorial(new BigInteger("6")));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Also you can use `BigInteger.valueOf(number)` .

Answer (score 6):

Ofcourse you can use `BigInteger` to calculate large number's factorial. See this;

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int number) {
    BigInteger factorial = BigInteger.ONE;

    for (int i = number; i > 0; i--) {
        factorial = factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }

    return factorial;
}
```

Comment: the recursive approach looks prettier, doesn't it?

Comment: Of course , you can modify to recursive approach easily. I just added for how to calculate big values of factorial.